# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'

Tags: c#

Error message:

```
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.
```

What I am missing?

```
con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = null;
string sql = "select * from " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "where SUPP_NAME like ' " + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = dr;
GridView1.DataBind();
dr.Close();
dr = null;
```

If I input " A", the data will show the first of them have  A in first character.

Comment: Can you show us generated SQL Query ?

Comment: What are the values of `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` and `TextBox1.Text` when you debug your code?

Comment: yes the dropdown it ok but SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); this line

Comment: @iJay  show   massage the frist  of them if i input in box

Comment: Always remember that an exception has two things: a type (InvalidOperationException) and a message (that usually tells you exactly what is wrong). You have not posted the message so please do that.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @iJayAn exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1):

You have no space before the `WHERE` and you need to quote `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` unless it will always be a number. Use a method like this to quote it:

```
string SqlQuote(object o)
{
    if (o == null) return "null";
    return "'" + o.ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

But really, you should use parameterized queries to avoid all these problems with quoting, spacing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The sql command don't have associated connection. Set `cmd.Connection = con;` before call cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: how ? can u excample ?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

still erorr this

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.

```
 con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand= new SqlCommand("select * from ' " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " ' where SUPP_NAME like ' " + TextBox1.Text + "%' ");

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: what about %  for find character one of them ?

Comment: still error  this line SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
msg error this System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: SqlDataReader myReader = null;

Comment: @kanesmith What are the values of `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` and `TextBox1.Text` **exactly**?

Comment: @SonerGönül dropdown it work but  when i input values in textbox1 this line error   myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();